# Suggestions required to generate Code Churn Report

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I've been asked to generate code churn report, but I don't have any clue on how to do it.

As a company, we are using DevOps On-Premises server.

After some analysis, I found that below articles could be helpful to achieve my requirement.

[Analyze and report on code churn and coverage using the code churn and run coverage perspectives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/perspective-code-analyze-report-code-churn-coverage?view=azure-devops-2020#example-code-churn-report)

[Create Excel reports from a work item query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports?view=azure-devops-2020)

And the below article is to describe about how to setup the environment.

[Add reports to a team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/add-reports-to-a-team-project?view=azure-devops-2020)

But, these articles are available under **SQL Server Reporting (Legacy)** section. I could not understand what does "Legacy" refers here.

Can anyone please suggest me if there is some better way to generate Code Churn Report, or is this the only alternative!

Comment: Hi @Ashokkumar, Is the explanation in my answer helpful to you? Please check with it. Any question about this, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**`Legacy`**" means the "**SQL Server reporting**" feature is the old preferred way for reporting.

Now, the new preferred way recommended for reporting is "**Analytics service**" feature with "**Power BI integration**", and currently this feature is in "**`Preview`**". More details, you can see "[**Analytics & Power BI integration (Preview)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops-2019)".

And please also reference to "[**Reporting roadmap for Azure DevOps**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/reporting-roadmap?view=azure-devops-2019)".

You can choose any one of the two ways to generate reporting in your Azure DevOps Server 2019. This depends on which way you and your company prefer to use.